# while build a demo about ffmpeg , it occurs : undefined reference to `av_register_all'

Tags: ffmpeg

This problem has bothered me for days.

After I compile and install ffmpeg , I try to build a demo using it, but it always fails.

The demo is:

```
#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
#include "libavformat/avformat.h"

int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
    av_register_all();
    return 1;
}
```

With `gcc main.c -o main.o`, an error occurs: `undefined reference to 'av_register_all'`

Building with: `gcc main.c -o main.o  -lm -ld -lz -lavcodec -lavformat -lavutil`, another error occurs: `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ld`

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 12):

Putting includes within extern "C" block may work.

```
extern "C"{
    #include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
    #include <libavformat/avformat.h>
    #include <libswscale/swscale.h>
}
```

Comment: The code in the question is C code, or at least it can be compiled as such so I don't see how it helps

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned [here](http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2012-September/009837.html)
the order of libraries matters 
so in your case the following hopefully should work:

```
gcc main.c -o main.o -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil  -lz -lm -lpthread
```

Answer (score 3):

```
gcc filename.c -o outputfilename -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil  -lz -lm -lpthread -I'/usr/local/include' -lswresample
```

The above command will help to compile properly.

Comment: This worked for me: $ gcc filename.c -o outputfilename -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil  -lz -lm -lpthread -I'/usr/local/include'

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at how [this project](https://github.com/mpenkov/ffmpeg-tutorial) builds sample code.

The Makefile is pretty simple to follow.

Answer (score 0):

It's work for me:

```
gcc <your source code> -o main -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil -lm -lpthread -I'/usr/local/include' -lswresample
```